# getting started- Web services

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, web

I am getting started with web services.So can anyone please suggest me any tutorials,any books , examples or any such thing which can give me a head start in this domain.
I am completely new to this and i am looking for a good reference guide which will help me understand this.
Any help is highly appreciated.
Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

you can try classes from [Udacity](http://www.udacity.com/), relatively good and start from scratch. Also [Google code university](http://code.google.com/edu/) has many great tutorials!

Answer (score 0):

Always start with reading. Shortfly after, practice.

[Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service)

[W3 tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/default.asp)

[SOAP](http://www.w3schools.com/soap/soap_intro.asp)

[xml tut](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp)